# automate (no user) div with canvas img to send to twitter

Tags: php, jquery, html, screenshot

Is it possible for cron to start a script that will create a canvas using live data (a chart) and text wrapped in a div. Then covert the div into a image, basically a screenshot, and send the img file too Twitter.  Can this be done without any user interaction, and so nothing on the screen ?

In theory I cannot see why it would not work, but its the drawing more, than the image sending, that has me confused.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the chart requires javascript to be visualized, then no. PHP cannot execute javascript by itself.

Comment: Yes you can do this quite easily provided you have a browser installed on the server. A headless browser such as phantomJS would be the simplest solution

Comment: I do not think the server has a browsers, would this be the only way of doing it ?

Comment: Installing phantomjs is as simple as uploading a binary file, but no its not the only option, there are various services that do this and have an Api.